# Cómo hacer un visitador que reciba una clase hija de JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing, spring, genericos

tengo unas ventanas y como se interconectan para hacer la navegación, obtengo dependencias cíclicas, por lo que estoy tratando de implementar el patrón visitador para evitar este problema mediante la arquitectura.

Ahora, porsi se me olvida o después crece mucho la aplicación le quiero meter un método genérico que me acepte un frame culquiera, lo saque del contenedor IOC de Spring y lo muestre, pero el código no me compila.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
public abstract class NavigationHandler {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public void <T> goToFrame(JFrame origin, Class<T extends JFrame> target) {
        Class<T> aFrame = context.getBean(target);
        aFrame.setVisible(true);
        origin.dispose();
    }

    public abstract void goToMenu(JFrame origin);

.
.
.

}
```

me arroja

> expected

¿Cómo puedo corregir mi declaración de método?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre se me olvida el órden de la declaración:

```
[modificador de acceso] [declaración del tipo] [tipo de retorno] [nombre de método]([Tipo Genérico] [nombre de variable])
```

Ese es e órden correcto.

```
public <T extends JFrame> void goToFrame(JFrame origin, Class<T> target) {
      T aFrame = context.getBean(target);
      aFrame.setVisible(true);
      origin.dispose();
}
```

Y la forma de llamarlo es:

```
navigationHandler.goToFrame(this, Menu.class);
```