# ¿Cómo crear una ventana (menú) que al pulsar un botón abra una segunda ventana?

Tags: java, java-swing, botón

Me explico; estoy tratando de crear un menú donde hay 3 opciones **modificar, ver y añadir**. Al selecionar una de la 3 opciones me gustaría que se abriera una segunda ventana donde se pueda, por ejemplo, introducir un texto y comprobar que ese texto es correcto mediante un botón. Esto yo lo sabría hacer en dos códigos separados, es decir, abriendo 2 ventanas independientes cada una en un código diferente, pero si deseo hacer que una ventana abra otra esto ¿cómo sería?

Dejo lo que he intentado hacer(no abre la segunda ventana):

```
public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JFrame frameDos;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    Main windowDos = new Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    windowDos.frameDos.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Menu Java S.L.");
        frame.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnVer = new JButton("Ver");
        btnVer.setBounds(67, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnVer);

        JButton btnModificar = new JButton("Modificar ");
        btnModificar.setBounds(171, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnModificar);

        JButton btnAadir = new JButton("A\u00F1adir");
        btnAadir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                agregar();
            }
        });
        btnAadir.setBounds(275, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnAadir);

        JLabel lblConsulteModifiqueO = new JLabel("Consulte, modifique o a\u00F1ada una nueva empresa a la base de datos");
        lblConsulteModifiqueO.setBounds(41, 51, 414, 30);
        panel.add(lblConsulteModifiqueO);
    }

    private void agregar() {
        frameDos = new JFrame();
        frameDos.setTitle("Validador de empresas");
        frameDos.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 300);
        frameDos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameDos.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 1);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Introduce el nombre de la empresa: ");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 68, 204, 14);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(264, 67, 114, 20);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Validar");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                validar(textField.getText()); /* aqui va un metodo que no añado porque es irrelevante */
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(163, 93, 89, 23);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
```

**Que intento hacer con el codigo:**

Estoy tratando de agregar una segunda funcion llamada agregar() que funciona como una ventana al igual que la funcion inicialize() pero la añado al boton añadir, mi idea era que al pulsarlo abriera otra ventana pero no funciona de este modo, supongo, que no se hará así, he creado frameDos con la intención de que pudiera funcionar, pero nada que hacer, como se haría?

Comment: si está puesto en el código lo que no se si está en el lugar adecuando.

Comment: Si necesitas ahondar más en el patrón visitador te dejo una pregunta que hice aquí mismo hace un tiempo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286917/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-visitador-que-reciba-una-clase-hija-de-jframe

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! le voy a hechar una ojeadita

Comment: La solución es simple. Solo debes mostrar la ventana cuando el usuario presione el botón y asunto arreglado. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una corrección rápida de tu código nos deja algo así:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question355365;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JFrame frameDos;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();                    
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Menu Java S.L.");
        frame.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnVer = new JButton("Ver");
        btnVer.setBounds(67, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnVer);

        JButton btnModificar = new JButton("Modificar ");
        btnModificar.setBounds(171, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnModificar);

        JButton btnAadir = new JButton("A\u00F1adir");
        btnAadir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                agregar();
            }
        });
        btnAadir.setBounds(275, 92, 94, 23);
        panel.add(btnAadir);

        JLabel lblConsulteModifiqueO = new JLabel("Consulte, modifique o a\u00F1ada una nueva empresa a la base de datos");
        lblConsulteModifiqueO.setBounds(41, 51, 414, 30);
        panel.add(lblConsulteModifiqueO);
    }

    private void agregar() {
        frameDos = new JFrame();
        frameDos.setTitle("Validador de empresas");
        frameDos.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 300);
        frameDos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameDos.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 1);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Introduce el nombre de la empresa: ");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 68, 204, 14);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(264, 67, 114, 20);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Validar");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                validar(textField.getText());
                /* aqui va un metodo que no añado porque es irrelevante */
            }

            private void validar(String text) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(163, 93, 89, 23);
        frameDos.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        frameDos.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

## Cambios

Si Main es tu *dispatcher*, no necesitas tener dos, basta uno que haga bien su trabajo, por ello eliminamos

```
Main windowDos = new Main();
```

Esto nos deja claro el otro problema,

```
window.frameDos.setVisible(true);
```

se llama aunque no se hjaya dado click en agregar, por lo que frameDos no existe, así que toca cambiar de lugar esa línea y ponerla en el método `agregar` justo al final

```
  frameDos.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
  frameDos.setVisible(true);
```

## Explicación

La lógica de que mostrar reside en la clase `Main` en un intento de mantener una jerarquía, si bien la solución mostrada logrará de manera rudimentaria lo que queremos existen otras formas un poco más eficientes.

[image: diagrama de clases UML]

Como vemos lo que hace compleja a esta clase es que hace muchas cosas a la vez, y eso nos hace más complejo el resolver rápidamente algún problema.

El primer cambio que yo haría sería extraer la lógica de creación de la ventana uno y de la ventana dos a otras clases reducieno así la cantidad de código que se debe tener en cuenta a la vez.

Esto para seguir el primer principio de diseño de software parte de SOLID, Responsabilidad única.

## Mejoras

Una mejora muy importante que puedes hacer es el uso del Patrón Visitador.

Como tal vez sepas los patrones de diseño son soluciones probadas a problemas comunes y en el caso del patrón visitador está pensado específicamente para el problema de la navegación.

Como sabes la critica más fuerte a los patrones de diseño es que casi todos se puedden reducir a una abstracción, y en este caso aplica, lo que hacemos es abstraer la navegación en su propia clase, a la que podemos llamar por ejemplo `NavegadorDeVentanas`, y la idea es en el código simplemente llamar sus métodos y que se encargue de la navegación.
Por ejemplo, desde una ventana uno simplemente llamar a su instancia de navegador de ventanas y llamar a su método `irAValidacion`, o `irACobro`.

Esto nos permitiría agregar funcionalidades de una manera más fácil como la "modalidad", es decir, que solo puedas usar una ventana a la vez, o dicho como regla de negocios que haya un manejo consistente de los estados de navegación entre ventanas.

Si la ventana que deseas Mostrar no es muy compleja, en vez de usar el patrón visitador allí sinceramente te recomiendo usar la clase JDialog en vez de la clase JFrame, esto debido a que ya tiene la modalidad preprogramada y solo necesitas ponerle un componente padre como parámetro de su constructor y bloqueará el regreso a la ventana que lo llamó hasta que no se haya cerrado ese diálogo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Tu respuesta ha sido grandiosa y me ha ayudado muchísimo, ya que ya no sabía que hacer, para mi todo esto de jswing es nuevo y lo probe así un poco experimentando según yo creia que sería, pero obviamente no sabia como hacerlo de forma adecuada y en internet no fui capaz de dar con lo correcto. Tu respuesta ha sido muy detallada y muy bien explicada, de nuevo muchas gracias! me has ayudado mucho :)